# How to skip assembly code when debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Sometimes when I use the debugger to step through my code, it goes into some assembly code (I guess I've stepped into some system library code).

The question is, how can I skip over it and jump to the nearest c++ code of my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Step-out" button or Shift+F11, this will step back up the call stack.

Alternatively display the call stack (Alt+7), then double click on the function level you want to return to; this will indicate in the source window where the call was made. Then in the source window right-click the statement following the call, and select "Run to cursor".  Of course if you already know where the call came from, you could just use "Run to cursor" in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can close that assembly window by clicking X on right side in the code window. Not the one at top most right(which closes the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Jump Out of the current function? (Shift-F11 in the C++ settings?)